# Background-image change on click angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to change a background image on click but I am getting an error with the syntax, am i doing something wrong ?

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'background': 'url('../../assets/pngs/btn_answeroption_selected.png') no-repeat'}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following way,

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + image_url+ ')'}"></div>
```